# JS - Filtering Promise object

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Iv'e been trying to filter data (sampleProducts) that i got from firebase. The problem is that sampleProducts data is defined as Promise object since i used then() method to extract it like this:

```
import fire from "./config/FBConfig"

var sampleProducts = fire.firestore().collection("sampleProducts").doc("dogvrgMGe2rBJkCy7tIw").get().then((doc) => {
        return Object.values(doc.data());  
});
```

I try to filter the data like this:

```
import { sampleProducts } from './Data'

class Api {
    usePriceFilter = usePriceFilter === 'true' && true
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {

                let data = sampleProducts.filter(item => {
                    if (
                        usePriceFilter &&
            (item.price < minPrice || item.price > maxPrice)
                    ) {
                        return false
                    }

                    if (category === 'home') {
                        return true
                    }

                    if (category !== 'All categories' && category !== item.category)
                        return false

                    if (term && !item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))
                        return false

                    return true
                })

                let totalLength = data.length
                data = this.sortByPrice(data, sortValue)
                data = data.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)
                resolve({ data, totalLength })
            }, 500)
        })
    }
}
```

So since sampleProducts is Promise i cant filter it, this is the error and the data in console:
[error + data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXzOy.png)

Will be happy for any help or suggestions. thanks.

Comment: it's saying that 'sampleProducts.filter' is not a function, I would console.log(sampleProdcuts.filter) it or debug it to see what it actually is

Comment: It’s a promise. You need to access to the resolved value of sampleProducts using then().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first resolve the promise before you can perform a `filter` on it.

If you only need a single item, consider using `find` instead of `filter`.

When sorting, consider following more of a functional style of programming. I've updated the example to show how to use `Array.sort` function to achieve this.

```js
function getSampleProducts() {
  return Promise.resolve([
    {id: 1, price: 2},
    {id: 2, price: 3},
    {id: 3, price: 1},
  ]);
}

const sampleProducts = getSampleProducts();

function getItemUsingID(id) {
  return sampleProducts
    .then(products => {
      return products.find(x => x.id === parseInt(id, 12))
    });      
}

function getProductsSortedByPrice(page, pageSize) {
  return sampleProducts
    .then(products => {
      return products
        .filter(p => true /* filter logic here */)
        .sort(propertySorter(p => p.price))
        .slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    });
}

function propertySorter(selector) {
  return (a, b) => {
    const valA = selector(a);
    const valB = selector(b);

    if (valA > valB) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (valA < valB) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

getItemUsingID('1')
  .then(result => console.log('getItemUsingID', result))
  
getProductsSortedByPrice(1, 2)
  .then(result => console.log('getProductsSortedByPrice', result))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still need to use filter on another part of my code, i edited the post, would be really happy if its possible for any help or suggestion on that

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use `filter`. The primary suggestion was to use `find` if you only need one item. I've updated the answer to also include suggestions for sorting.